# Accessing the file stream column is too slow in SQL Server machine

Tags: .net, sql-server, filestream

I have two servers. One is an application server which is an ASP.NET application (DotNetNuke) and the second one is a database server. Both servers are on the same network.

When I send a simple query from the application server everything is fine and fast but if I send a query, for example, select just one row that contains a file stream column (`varbinary(max)` it takes at least 10 seconds.

The size of the image and video files in the file stream column is from 5 to 10 MB.
We are using windows server 2012 for both servers and the version of the SQL Server is 2014. Below you can see an example of a query that takes a long time when we have two servers instead of one server:

```
SELECT [MEDIUM_ID],
[FILE_STREAM].PathName() as FILE_PATH,[FILE_STREAM] FROM MEDIUMS WHERE MEDIUM_ID=12";
```

Would be fine if anybody help me in this regard.

Comment: Does it takes 10 seconds when you do this query from your asp.net.application only, or also when you do it from an SSMS on the application server ?

Comment: both of them are the same and take 10 seconds. The problem is not the asp.net application. I created a simple console application and I saw the problem again.

Comment: Maybe something with your network,  how long does it takes to copy a 5 to 10 MB file from the database server to your application server ? Just trying to rule out anything else then a database problem so your not looking on the wrong place for this problem

Comment: Do you mean the problem can not be from a database or file stream configuration...

Comment: No that is not what I mean, I mean you should test if the problem is not network related before you start searching what could be wrong with the database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Filestreams are stored outside the database in the SQL Server's filesystem. Are the database files and filestreams stored remotely from the SQL Server, over an SMB share?

Comment: No, it's located in the SQL server machine